# Why is 'type: module' in package.json file?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I upgraded the node and built the existing file.

But it didn't build, and there was an error.

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module:                          │
   │   ~~/nuxt.config.js                                      │
   │   require() of ES modules is not supported.                                            │
   │   require() of ~~/nuxt.config.js from                    │
   │   ~~/config.js is an ES   │
   │   module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type":   │
   │   "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.            │
   │   Instead rename nuxt.config.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use       │
   │   import(), or remove "type": "module" from                                            │
   │   ~~/package.json.
```

So I removed 'type: module' in package.json file.

Is it okay to remove it?

Answer (score 201):

When you have `"type": "module"` in the `package.json` file, your source code should use `import` syntax. When you do not have, you should use `require` syntax; that is, adding `"type": "module"` to the `package.json` enables ES 6 modules. For more info, see [here](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v13.x/api/esm.html#esm_enabling).

Comment: I think what Alex was trying to say is that omitting `type` from `package.json` has the same effect as setting it to CJS. (This is what the spec says: "If the nearest parent package.json lacks a "type" field, or contains "type": "commonjs", .js files are treated as CommonJS. If the volume root is reached and no package.json is found, Node.js defers to the default, a package.json with no "type" field.")

Comment: Somthing to be noted: it will apply to all exports. So I don't know how to mix commonjs and ESM yet.

Comment: can i still use require syntax after add type module in package.json file?

Answer (score 31):

#### Update as of mid-2022

If you're using Node.js v16, and you should if you can since it's LTS, you only need to use `type: module` as explained here: https://blog.logrocket.com/es-modules-in-node-today/

---

If you're still stuck with a lower version of Node.js for some reasons, you can follow this blog post from Flavio: https://flaviocopes.com/how-to-enable-es-modules-nodejs/

And do the following:

- add `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`
- use `--experimental-modules` when launching your app, eg: `node --experimental-modules app.js`

Or you can do one of those instead if on a modern version of Node already:

- add `"type": "module"` in your `package.json`
- rename your file with an `.mjs` extension, end result will look like this `node app.mjs`

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you still need to either (a) declare `"type": "module"` in package.json or (b) use .mjs file extensions when using Node 14 (tested with version 14.17.3). Otherwise you get an error from Node like `Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.` and `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`. This also applies to Node 16.5.0.

Comment: @superEb Nvm, you're right, `type: module` is still required. My bad:  https://blog.logrocket.com/es-modules-in-node-today/

Answer (score 3):

@AfsharMohebi's answer is excellent and covers the most useful points.

This answer is to add some color around CI/CD pipelines, where one may need to utilize adding a dynamic `type` parameter for executing code with node, written in ES6 JavaScript. Additionally, I am aware this is tangential to the OP's question but Google brought me here and so hopefully this is found useful by someone else.

In particular, we may use `--input-type=module` according to the [node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_input_type_flag) *if we do not have a `package.json` including `type: module`*.

For example, I use the command below to test that an npm package was uploaded successfully and is usable:

```
mkdir test-mypkg && cd test-mypkg 
echo "import { myFunc } from '@myname/myPkg';" > test.js 
npm i @myname/myPkg @babel/core @babel/node && cat test.js | node --input-type=module
```

> *Note: `babel` dependencies are included for full ES6 to ES5 transpilation and may/may not be necessary. In addition, you should probably pin the version of the package `myPkg` you're testing!*

Answer (score 3):

From the [Node documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#type)

> The "type" field defines the module format that Node.js uses for all .js files that have that package.json file as their nearest parent.

> Files ending with .js are loaded as ES modules when the nearest parent package.json file contains a top-level field "type" with a value of "module".

> If the nearest parent package.json lacks a "type" field, or contains "type": "commonjs", .js files are treated as CommonJS.

So by default, Node treats `.js` files as CommonJS Module (i.e. you can use `require` and `module.exports`).

If you want to use ES Module, you should add `"type": "module"` in your package.json so that Node treats `.js` files as ES Module (i.e. you can `import` and `export`)

Answer (score 2):

When you switch from `const express = require("express")` to `import { Express } from "express";` you will have to insert `"type": "module"` in your package.json.
It is basically used to enable the ES6 modules import/export syntax.

Answer (score 1):

With Node.js version [v20.10.0](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v20.10.0) or later, the `"type": "module"` declaration in the `package.json` file is no longer necessary.

Instead, execute your program using the [`--experimental-detect-module`](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v20.10.0#detect-esm-syntax-in-ambiguous-javascript) flag:

```bash
node --experimental-detect-module index.js
```

Alternatively, you can achieve the same result with the [`--experimental-default-type="module"`](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v20.10.0#--experimental-default-type-flag-to-flip-module-defaults) flag:

```bash
node --experimental-default-type="module" index.js
```

To avoid adding the flag every time, include it in the `package.json` file within the "scripts" section like this:

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node --experimental-detect-module index.js"
  },
  ...
}
```

Now, you can run your program using:

```bash
npm run start
```

This approach works well even without the presence of `"type": "module"` anywhere else in your project.