# ts-jest cannot use top level await even with correct tsconfig

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm trying to use a top level await during testing with Jest but Jest complains that

```
error TS1378: Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', or 'nodenext', and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher.
```

Here's the file (`src/lib/mongodb.ts`)which is problematic:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import mongoUri from 'mongo-uri-tool';
import { getMongoURI } from './settings/settings.js';

const getConnectionOptions = () => {
  const uri = getMongoURI();

  return {
    uri,
    parsedUri: mongoUri.parseUri(uri),
  };
};

const connectToMongoDB = async () => {
  const connectionOptions = getConnectionOptions();

  const mongodb = await MongoClient.connect(connectionOptions.uri);

  return mongodb.db(connectionOptions.parsedUri.db);
};

export const MongoDB = await connectToMongoDB();
```

Here's the test (`src/api/trips/trips.test.ts`) file which is ultimately import the above:

```
import { Trips } from './index'; // <--------- this is the import which leads to importing mongodb
import generateId from '../../lib/generateId';

describe('find trip by id', () => {
  test('find trip by id', async () => {
    const id = generateId();
    const slug = 'lol';
    await Trips.insertOne({ _id: id, slug });

    const trip = await Trips.findOne({ _id: id });
    expect(trip._id).toStrictEqual(id);
  });
});
```

When I run `npx tsc` no problems are reported:

```
11:12AM /Users/paymahn/code/tripvector/tripvector-mono/backend testing ✭ ✱ ➜ ◼
 ❮❮❮ npx tsc
11:12AM /Users/paymahn/code/tripvector/tripvector-mono/backend testing ✭ ✱ ➜ ◼
```

Here's my `tsconfig.json` which has the correct `module` and `target`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "sourceMap": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "allowJs": true,
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "lib": ["es2022", "DOM"],
      "module": "es2022",
      "target": "es2017",
      "rootDir": "src",
      "baseUrl": ".",
      "paths": {
        "*": ["node_modules/*", "src/types/*"]
      },
      "types": ["node", "jest"],
      "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types", "src/types"],
      "outDir": "./built"
    },
    "include": ["./src/**/*", "jest.config.js"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
  }
```

and here's my `jest.config.cjs`:

```
const { jsWithTsESM: tsjPreset } = require("ts-jest/presets");

module.exports = {
  ...tsjPreset,
  globals: {
    "ts-jest": {
      tsconfig: "tsconfig.json",
    }
  },
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "js"],
  testRegex: ".*.test.ts"
};
```

Here's my project structure:

[image]

Why is it that Jest and ts-jest complain that I can't use a top-level await but `tsc` and my IDE (Webstorm) don't complain at all? How can I correctly configure Jest and ts-jest to allow top level awaits with ESM for both JS and TS files (I'm slowly migrating from JS to TS)?

Note that Jest was working great until I added the first test which relies on a top level await. It seems I have Jest and ts-jest correctly configured to work with ESM and a mix of JS and TS files. The new problem is figuring out top level awaits with ts-jest.

EDIT: if I add `@ts-ignore` to the problematic top level await, I get another similar issue reported by Jest:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
// @ts-ignore
export const MongoDB = await connectToMongoDB();
```

```
    Details:

    /Users/paymahn/code/tripvector/tripvector-mono/backend/src/lib/mongodb.ts:24
    exports.MongoDB = await connectToMongoDB();
                      ^^^^^

    SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules
```

Could this be an issue of which version of node I'm using? I'm currently using v17:

```
11:53AM /Users/paymahn/code/tripvector/tripvector-mono/backend testing ✭ ✱ ➜ ◼
 ❯❯❯ node --version
v17.6.0
11:53AM /Users/paymahn/code/tripvector/tripvector-mono/backend testing ✭ ✱ ➜ ◼
 ❯❯❯ npm --version
7.6.0
```

EDIT: interesting, I migrated to mocha and executing mocha with `-n loader=ts-node/esm` works perfectly. I wonder what's going on with jest...

Comment: If you like to check it out, I ran into a similar issue and resolved it. See repro repo https://github.com/RimuTec/express-testing I then got stuck on an issue with vscode-jest-runner which I observe for the "Debug" only but not for the "Run" command. I've filed an issue https://github.com/firsttris/vscode-jest-runner/issues/278 Although this latter issue may be unrelated to your scenario, perhaps the repro repo with its config may help, in particular see setting for "module" in "tsconfig.json".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jest won't accept top-level-awaits with NodeJS16 & TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70725063/jest-wont-accept-top-level-awaits-with-nodejs16-typescript)

Comment: You're not the only one, almost everyone using TS Jest has had this issue.