# ts-jest says "Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed..." but I already set "target": "ES2022", "module": "ES2022"

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm getting this error when trying to run a new test:

```bash
error TS1378: Top-level 'await' expressions are only allowed when the 'module' option is set to 'es2022', 'esnext', 'system', 'node16', or 'nodenext', and the 'target' option is set to 'es2017' or higher.
```

But server/tsconfig.json already has:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2022",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "ES2022",
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "lib": ["ES2021.String"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "composite": true /* Enable project compilation https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html */
  },
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "../src"
    },
    {
      "path": "../shared"
    }
  ]
}
```

My Jest test looks like:

```
test('something', async () => {
  await updateTransactions();
  // ...
}
```

and updateTransactions.ts looks like:

```
const connectionString = process.env.POSTGRESQL_CONNECTION_STRING;
const pgClient = new pg.Client({ connectionString });
await pgClient.connect();

export async function updateTransactions() {
   // ...
}
```

I've already looked at questions like [Top-level ‘await’ expressions are only allowed when the ‘module’ option is set to ‘esnext'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66486903/top-level-await-expressions-are-only-allowed-when-the-module-option-is-set-t) and [How can I use async/await at the top level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515764/how-can-i-use-async-await-at-the-top-level?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I know that I could refactor `await pgClient.connect();` to be within a function, but for various reasons, I'm curious how to just enable top-level await instead.

Comment: Because you showed a snippet from a test and said that it's a Jest test, I'm guessing this error occurs when running the test in Jest. Have you read [the documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules) for running Jest in ESM mode? By default it runs in CJS mode where TLA is **not** supported, and ESM support is only experimental for Jest. If you need to run tests on ESM code, Jest is probably going to present some challenges.

Comment: You might be able to get it to work by putting `preset: 'ts-jest/presets/default-esm'` and `transform: {'^.+\\.tsx?$': ['ts-jest', {tsconfig: '<rootDir>/server/tsconfig.json',useESM: true}]}` in your `jest.config.js` and call jest with `node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js`.

Comment: I went ahead and refactored not to use a top-level await: https://github.com/NEARFoundation/tx-tracking-app/commit/2ddbd60564eb6b795fcd5e9c31fb842789f67158#diff-e32a1e570a3cff680a4e3b1335dc66cd816ab14bc9bff451d5f5d467e0278abeR74 I'd be curious though if someone wants to offer a commit that would make it work while still using a top-level await.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jest won't accept top-level-awaits with NodeJS16 & TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70725063/jest-wont-accept-top-level-awaits-with-nodejs16-typescript)

Comment: Did you try changing moduleResolution to nodenext?

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding "ts-jest/presets/default-esm" preset like below solved the issue.

jest.config.js:

```
export default {
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "(.+)\\.js": "$1",
    },
    preset: 'ts-jest/presets/default-esm', // or other ESM presets
}
```

Ref: https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/esm-support/#use-esm-presets