# Why does my jest setup not work with top-level await

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, jestjs, babel-jest

I have a top-level await to load application secrets as follows:

```js
// lib/config/secrets.ts
const secrets = await loadSecrets();
export default secrets;
```

I import this in other modules for db connection setup, etc:

```js
// lib/db/index.ts
import { Pool } from "pg";
import secrets from "lib/config/secrets";

const pool = new Pool({
   connectionString: secrets.dbUrl,
   ...
});
```

This works fine when running my application via Webpack, but when running unit tests with jest, I get the following error:
`SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`.
I've been stuck on this for some time and have even considered other avenues to avoid the asynchronous secret loading altogether since I haven't found a solution. I've seen this similar question [Jest won't accept top-level-awaits with NodeJS16 & TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70725063/jest-wont-accept-top-level-awaits-with-nodejs16-typescript), but I'm not using `ts-jest` in my project. Is there anything obvious about my configuration that would cause this issue during tests, or is this just not supported?

My `next.config.js` to support top-level await via Webpack:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.experiments.topLevelAwait = true;
    return config;
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

My `jest.config.js`:

```js
const nextJest = require("next/jest");

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  // Provide the path to your Next.js app to load next.config.js and .env files in your test environment
  dir: "./",
});

// Add any custom config to be passed to Jest
const customJestConfig = {
  moduleDirectories: ["node_modules", "<rootDir>"],
  modulePaths: ["<rootDir>/lib"],
  //   setupFilesAfterEnv: ["<rootDir>/jest.setup.js"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    // Handle module aliases (this will be automatically configured for you soon)
    "^components/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/components/$1",
    "^lib/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/lib/$1",
    "^pages/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/pages/$1",
  },
  testEnvironment: "jest-environment-jsdom",
};

// createJestConfig is exported this way to ensure that next/jest can load the Next.js config which is async
module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```

My `package.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "app",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
     ...
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager": "^3.199.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.3.1",
    "@mui/material": "^5.4.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "next": "^12.1.0",
    "next-auth": "^4.2.1",
    "npm": "^8.4.1",
    "pg": "^8.7.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.16.7",
    "@types/aws-lambda": "^8.10.108",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/node": "17.0.8",
    "@types/pg": "^8.6.5",
    "@types/react": "17.0.38",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.11.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.11.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.5.1",
    "esbuild": "^0.15.12",
    "eslint": "8.6.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.8",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^7.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^2.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "typescript": "4.5.4"
  }
}
```

My `.babelrc`:

```json
{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": []
}
```

My `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "components": ["components/"],
      "lib": ["lib/"],
      "sql": ["sql/"],
      "styles": ["styles/"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["types/*.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

###### Update:

I tried adding `"type":"module"` to the `package.json` and updating the jest.config and next.config extensions to `.cjs`. It still produces the same error: `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jest won't accept top-level-awaits with NodeJS16 & TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70725063/jest-wont-accept-top-level-awaits-with-nodejs16-typescript)

Comment: Hi @gunwin, I mention this same question in my description. I'm not using `ts-jest`.

Comment: Your package is not an es module so jest loads it as commonjs. This part `and the top level bodies of modules`.

Comment: Hi @morganney, I switched the package `type` to `module` and still get this error. Did you mean something else by switching to an es module?

Comment: I have the same issue, I do not use ts in my project. Did you manage to solve this?