# Nuxt 3 in AWS Lambda with Serverless Framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nuxtjs3

I try to deploy simple Nuxt 3 application to AWS Lambda for SSR. So far I have:

in nitro.config.ts

```
import { defineNitroConfig } from 'nitropack';

export default defineNitroConfig({
  preset: 'aws-lambda',
  serveStatic: true
});
```

in Lambda handler

```
import { handler } from './output/server/index.mjs';

export const runner = (event, context) => {
  const { statusCode, headers, body } = handler({ rawPath: '/' });

  return {
    statusCode,
    body,
    headers
  }
}
```

in serverless.yaml

```
functions:
  ssr:
    handler: handler.runner
    timeout: 15
    package:
      individually: true
      include:
        - output/**
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: '*'
          method: '*'
```

I run `yarn build`, change `.output` folder name to `output` to be able to include it with package, but I still have errors like `"errorMessage": "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"`.

Is someone has idea how it could be done?

Comment: This may help you, put `module` as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61401475/8816585

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its easier than that bro, nuxt already exports the handler nothing for us to do:

**serverles.yml**:

```
service: nuxt-app-lamba

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  stage: dev
  region: us-east-1

functions:
  nuxt:
    handler: .output/server/index.handler
    events:
      - httpApi: '*'
```

**nuxt.config.ts**:

```
// https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/configuration/nuxt.config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    nitro: {
        preset: 'aws-lambda',
        serveStatic: true
      }
})
```

**package.json**:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "build:lamba": "NITRO_PRESET=aws-lambda nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare",
    "deploy": "sls deploy"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nuxt": "3.0.0-rc.11"
  }
}
```

This example is not working anymore (2022.12.09):

**Working example**: https://8cyysz2g5f.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

Comment: My man, you saved me from hell. Took me hours and hours!!

Comment: Greetings with the latest version of nuxt js I get the output generated as .output/server/index.mjs. hence I get the error like this 

`Cannot find module './.output/server/index.js' Require stack: - /var/task/s_nuxt.js - /var/runtime/index.mjs`