# Has anyone been able to deploy Nuxt 3 into AWS Amplify or Lambda with SSR enabled?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nuxt.js, aws-amplify, server-side-rendering

Recently I have been all over my head with deploying nuxt 3 application with `SSR` support into AWS Amplify. Apparently even they have mentioned they support nuxt and next deployment with `SSR` support in [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/09/amplify-javascript-adds-server-side-rendering-support-frameworks-next-js-nuxt-js/#:%7E:text=When%20using%20Amplify%20JavaScript%20to%20build%20web%20applications%2C%20you%20can%20now%20incorporate%20server%2Dside%20rendering%20(SSR)%20with%20frameworks%20like%20Next.js%20and%20Nuxt.js.), it seems like it is quite misleading. I have tried for days to deploy it to Amplify but didn't work. After quite a digging I found these two github issues mentioning that it doesn't support `SSR` deployment with nuxt.

1. https://github.com/nuxt/website-v2/issues/1091
2. https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/1860

Then I turned to deploy into AWS Lambda with the use of `serverless framework`. I found out in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73928788/12272450) that we could do it with nuxt 3. But it is failing with the following error `Cannot find module 'my-app/.output/server/index'`.

Below is my setup

**serverless.yaml**

```
service: my-app

frameworkVersion: "3"

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs18.x
  memorySize: 2048
  stage: dev
  timeout: 900
  region: us-east-1

functions:
  nuxt:
    handler: .output/server/index.handler
    events:
      - httpApi: '*'
```

**nuxt.config.ts**

```
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  ssr: false,
  nitro: {
    preset: 'aws-lambda'
  }
})
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "build:lambda": "NITRO_PRESET=aws-lambda nuxt build",
    "dev": "nuxt dev",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview",
    "postinstall": "nuxt prepare",
    "deploy": "sls deploy"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/devtools": "latest",
    "@types/node": "^18.17.3",
    "nuxt": "^3.6.5"
  }
}
```

---

I have three queries,

1. Is Amplify approach not possible yet with `SSR`?
2. Is Lambda deployment with `serverless framework` also not working with nuxt 3?
3. If above are not options, what would be the best approach to deploy a nuxt 3 application with `SSR` support into AWS?

Appreciate the help for any one of my queries.

Comment: Have you find a solution for this?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I have managed to deploy the nuxt 3 application into `AWS-lambda` with the `serverless-framework`. But there were some issues with loading my application images. Other than that it worked fine.
But regarding `AWS-Amplify` it seems like SSR support is not yet available. Were you seeking an answer for Lambda approach or the Amplify approach?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim if it is the Lambda approach I might be able to help you out

Answer (score 0):

There's now a nitro preset for AWS Amplify- https://github.com/unjs/nitro/pull/1912

https://nitro.unjs.io/deploy/providers/aws-amplify

You should be able to deploy Nuxt3 apps on AWS Amplify using the preset