# Test failing with "ReferenceError: fetch is not defined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have `node-fetch` installed, but the rest of the files in the project aren't importing it and the tests for them aren't failing

```
import { IQuery } from 'models/IQuery.interface';
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { handleProxyResponse } from 'utils/handleProxyResponse.util';
import { appendApiRoute, getDefaultHeaders, getLocale } from 'utils/proxy.util';

export const getContentPage = async (locale: string, publicId: string) => {
    const headers = getDefaultHeaders();
    //fetch is undefined here
    const response = fetch(appendApiRoute(`static-content/v1/${locale}/pages/${publicId}`), {
        method: 'GET',
        headers
    });

    return response;
};

export default async (request: NextApiRequest, response: NextApiResponse) => {
    const currentLocale = getLocale(request);
    const { query } = request;
    const { slug } = query as IQuery;

    const result = await getContentPage(currentLocale, slug);

    return handleProxyResponse(result, response);
};
```

Failing test:

```
it('should return handledProxyResponse', async () => {
    const result = await contentProxy(defaultRequest, response);

    expect(result).toEqual(handleProxyResponseReturnValue);
});
```

Comment: Maybe wrong node version? `fetch` is a built-in node function since v. 17.5. In the previous versions, you need to import it.

Comment: Did you add module type to package.json. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61401475/why-is-type-module-in-package-json-file

Answer (score -6):

May be it is a Issue of version. so you can try by use an external module

```
`npm install node-fetch`
```

then import it in your code

```
import fetch from "node-fetch"
```

Comment: as I mentioned above, I do have it installed already. It's build-in Node function since v.17.5. Also gives me "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" and "import http from 'node:http';"

Comment: You need to import it as like this  and it will work.
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

Comment: Already mentioned OP has node-fetch installed