# how to import JS function inside cypress.config.js

Tags: javascript, cypress, es6-modules

I have an `email.js` file which has a function called `email_func` and I want to call that function inside the `after:run` block inside cypress.config.js file.

However, I am getting the following error when I try to `require()` it.

> Your configFile is invalid: D:\Cypress-automation\cypress-automation\cypress.config.js
> It threw an error when required, check the stack trace below:
>
> **ReferenceError**: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
> This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'D:\Cypress-automation\cypress-automation\package.json' contains "type": "module".
> To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.

In email.js file I did export as follows

```js
const email_var = new emailClass();
module.exports = email_var;
```

and in cypress.config.js I am trying to do import like this but no luck

```js
const email_var = require('./cypress/support/email');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much research,following worked for me

in email.js exported variable in this manner

```
 exports.email_var = new emailClass();
```

in cypress.config.js imported in this manner

```
const { email_var } = require('./cypress/support/email.js');
```

Now, I can call my function as follows

```
email_var.email_function(results);
```

Answer (score 4):

There's almost two languages when it comes to javascript modules, the older cjs using `require()` and the newer `es modules`.

Since you have `"type": "module"` in `package.json`, you are opting for the latter.

Therefore, `cypress.config.js` will already have

```js
import { defineConfig }  from 'cypress'

export default defineConfig({
  ...
```

You need to use `import` for `email.js`

```js
import { defineConfig }  from 'cypress'
import email_var from './cypress/support/email.js'

export default defineConfig({
  ...
```

Plus you need to export in the es-modules style

```js
const email_var = new emailClass();
// module.exports = email_var;
export default email_var;
```

For more general discussion, see [Why is 'type: module' in package.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62554884/16997707)

Comment: I have tried these steps but still getting the same error,

in my package.json - I did not had "type": "module", but I went ahead and added that and in email.js I did export as below 

const email_var = new emailClass();
export default email_var;
 
and did try to import that in cypress.config.js as follows 

import email_var from './cypress/support/email.js'

Do I need to do anything differently ? please suggest.