# Cannot use import statement outside a module for npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am trying to use the npm package editly.

`import Editly from "editly"`

However when i try to import it i get this error.

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
> at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
> at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1176:20)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:27)
> at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

All the solutions i have viewed say to add "type": "module" to package.json but it already has it

Comment: Why didn't you share package.json code? It should work as [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68558580/12737879) if you have it in the top upmost level by that I mean make sure it's not nested in some other property by mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Check your node version! you need upgrade to 16 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating node. Maybe your node version is outdated. uninstall node and reinstall again.