Can you import Supertest as a ES6 module?
I am trying to use Jest with Supertest package to test my API. I tried using import { request } from "supertest"; to be able to use request in my file but got a SyntaxError saying that the module supertest does not provide an export called 'request'.

Any idea on how to use it this way?

You should consider creating a PR or issue to get this added to the documentation

supertest provides the function through a default export, so you will do
import request from "supertest"

instead

Yes, that was what I was doing wrong. Thanks!

why am I getting this error with this implemetation: `import request from 'supertest';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`


@bcsta if you are using esm syntax, you will have to enable module support in your package.json file, or if you want to use cjs syntax, you will have to use const request = require("supertest") instead. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61401475/why-is-type-module-in-package-json-file
